# Chromium or chrome needed in vercel deployed laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, google-chrome, web-scraping, vercel

Recently i tried to implement in one of my projects the [ChromePHP library](https://github.com/chrome-php/chrome) to use the headless browser provided by it in my app. tried using pupheteer and browsershot but ChromePHP worked the best for me. the only problem is that the library depends on a chrome executable and looks for it in your local computer, this works fine in development but when i deploy my app to vercel the library cant find the chrome executable. any ideas of how i can make this work? should y copy a chrome instalation folder inside my project folder and overwrite the library chrome location to the project one? it seems too dumb of an idea to work. Any other ideas?

Tried to deploy a app using a chrome dependant library.
Expected it to work.
Result: App cant find chrome.

Comment: I don't know how you would solve this but puppeteer ships with its own chrome binary when you install it so it's not really a dumb idea if you wanted to go the same route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the driver from [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads), put it in anywhere in your repo, eg: resources folder,

Then you have to set this Environment variable `CHROME_PATH`, for example:

```bash
CHROME_PATH=/path/to/the/exexutable
```

Or you are also able to explicitly set up any executable of your choice when creating a new object. For instance "chromium-browser":

```php
$chromePath = '/path/to/chrome/executable';
$browserFactory = new BrowserFactory($chromePath);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, im going to test it. ill let you know if it works!